# cc.LayerColor strange error (cocos2d-js)

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm creating a LayerColor in cocos2d-js, from the documentation at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.0rc0/index.html

I'm using the exact same code from the documentation

```
var yellowBackground = cc.LayerColor.create(cc.color(255,255,0,255));
```

And I get this strange error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createBuffer' of null
  _p.ctor   CCLayerWebGL.js:59
  Class CCClass.js:127
  cc.LayerColor.create  CCLayer.js:633
  (anonymous function)  app.js:1
```

Line 1 in app.js is the line I quoted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I've tried that same line in my source and it works fine. All I can think of is:
a) Have you downloaded the latest .zip from cocos2d-x.org?
b) Where are you placing that line of code? You should be doing it within your game's main Scene, on it's `onEnter` method (and then follow it by `this.addChild(yellowBackground);` so it'll actually get displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this code and it works. u need to pass new to the cc.color().

```
var whiteBackground = cc.LayerColor.create(new cc.Color(255,255,255,255));
        this.addChild(whiteBackground);
```